# segnetの使い方について

Tags: python, python3, windows, 画像, 深層学習

Pythonで画像を領域ごとに分割しようとしたときに、segnetというモデルを使うとうまくいくという情報を聞いたので、Pythonでそれを動かしてみようと試みました。

しかし、以下のサイトでダウンロードしたフォルダにはファイルが様々に入っており、どれをどうすればプログラムが実行できるのかわかりません。
https://github.com/alexgkendall/caffe-segnet

自分で調べたところだと、caffeというものを導入してつかうということはわかったのですが、そのcaffeについても何がなんだかさっぱりわかりません。

caffe-segnetについて、そのプログラムをPythonで実行させる方法・手順を教えていただきたいです。

共感した 0

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/155151

Answer (score 1, accepted):

マルチポスト先で回答をいただきました。
よって、自己解決とさせていただきます。

回答内容：
Keras や Tensorflow で実装した segnet があるため、そちらの方を使用する。
（ https://qiita.com/uni-3/items/a62daa5a03a02f5fa46d ）